# How do I handle Cities in the analysis of covid-19 data?

Tags: plotting, data, geographics

For this map I am trying to find a way to have some kind of GeoRegionValuePlot and I just want only the biggest cities, not every town.  The shade of each city on the map will give the number of covid-19 cases in that city. TIA

Answer (score 3):

Using `CityData`:

```
cities = CityData[{Large, "Sweden"}];
values = Thread[cities -> RandomReal[1, 6]];
GeoRegionValuePlot[values]
```

[image: Output]

The built-in data source only has a statistics on the administrative region level, at least for Sweden. Here's how we can map that data to the cities and plot it:

```
data = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"];
cities = CityData[{Large, "Sweden"}];

administrativeRegionData = 
  Association @@ (#AdministrativeDivision -> # & /@ Normal@data[
       Select[#Country == Entity["Country", "Sweden"] &]
       ]);

administrativeRegions = #["AdministrativeDivision"] & /@ cities;
cityData = administrativeRegionData /@ administrativeRegions;
deaths = #["Deaths"]["LastValue"] & /@ cityData;
GeoRegionValuePlot@Thread[cities -> deaths]
```

[image]